# How to deactivate a managed trigger in a customer org for Mass-Data migration

Tags: apex, trigger, managed-package, isv

We have to do a major data migration on a customer org using our ISV product. We need to delete and insert large amounts of records who in some cases have complex triggers.

Is there a way to temporarily deactivate a packaged trigger that doesn't require coding?

Would it be possible to deactivate those triggers in a patch release and then just push that to a single customer org?

Any other idea are welcome.

Comment: Not an easy thing to do.. What about enhancing your product by including a custom setting in which you can deactivate your packaged triggers? Might make more customers happy if they have that in their own hands..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a patch with the trigger deactivated and push it to just that org, but that's not a long-term solution.

It looks like your product needs an enhancement to allow trigger deactivation in certain circumstances - use a hierarchy custom setting so that the triggers turn off for the integrating user and continue to work for the rest of the company.